# Compare values in an Access table and then make them unique if there is a match

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I am trying to make a properly unique ID in an MS Access database which has:

```
ID
123456
123456
123456
123457
123458
```

Clearly, `123456` is duplicated, so I would like to append a `.1` to the end, making the above now look like this:

```
ID
123456
123456.1
123456.2
123457
123458
```

I can do this in Excel using:

```
=IF(A2=A1,CONCATENATE(A1,".",COUNTIF(A1:A$3,A1)),A2)
```

but I cannot think how to do this in MS Access.

Comment: You can use SWITCH statement and check if an id already exist then insert a diffrent id

Answer (score 1):

You can use VBA:

```
Public Sub MakeUnique(sTableName As String, sFieldName As String)

    Dim sCurrentValue       As String
    Dim lDuplicateCounter   As Long

    With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [" & sFieldName & "] FROM [" & sTableName & "] ORDER BY [" & sFieldName & "];")
        If .BOF And .EOF Then
            MsgBox "No records found"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Do Until .EOF
            If .Fields(0) <> sCurrentValue Then
                sCurrentValue = .Fields(0)
                lDuplicateCounter = 1
            Else
                .Edit
                .Fields(0) = .Fields(0) & "." & lDuplicateCounter
                lDuplicateCounter = lDuplicateCounter + 1
                .Update
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```